# htaccess question and plugins.php

Tags: plugins, htaccess, mod-rewrite

Does anyone know what this is doing:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)?$ admin/index.php?a=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

I'm having a problem accessing `/wp-admin/plugins.php` and I'm not sure if it's caused by the `RewriteRule` in my `.htaccess` file.

The link for the plugins is `example.com/wp/wp-admin/plugins.php` but when I try going there it is going to `example.com/wp-admin/plugins.php` which of course is incorrect.

Comment: Is your home/siteurl option set to https://example.com/wp or just https://example.com?

Comment: "I'm having a problem accessing `/wp-admin/plugins.php`" - do you mean `/wp/wp-admin/plugins.php`? The `RewriteRule` directive you posted does not target that URL-path. However, there are usually other directives in `.htaccess` that allow existing files to be directly accessed. Does this URL map to an existing file?

Comment: home/siteurl is example.com/wp

Comment: And yes, it is /wp/wp-admin/plugins.php. So the correct url is example.com/wp/wp-admin/plugins.php.  When I click "Plugins" in wordpress backend it goes to example.com/wp-admin/plugins.php.  As a work around for this I added a 301 redirect in the root of my site (Redirect 301 /wp-admin/plugins.php https://example.com/wp/wp-admin/plugins.php" which has worked and I now can access the plugins in the backend of my wordpress site.  However, I would really like to know what has caused this.  Thanks